# How to extend android class with delphi xe5

Tags: java, android, delphi, class, delphi-xe5

I tried to extend a class/interface from "Androidapi.JNI.App.pas" (TJservice), I need to extend this class for make a service. Is it possible? How?

[some example of java/android service](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/)

I need to override method like : oncreate, onbind, ondestroy. But I don't know how.

I tried something like this:

```
 type Tandroidservice= class(TJService)
  function onBind(intent: JIntent): JIBinder; override;
  procedure onCreate; override;
  procedure onDestroy; override;
  procedure onStart(intent: JIntent; startId: Integer); override;
 end;
```

with this error:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(13): E2137 Method 'onBind' not found in base class
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(14): E2137 Method 'onCreate' not found in base class
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(15): E2137 Method 'onDestroy' not found in base class
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(16): E2137 Method 'onStart' not found in base class
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(13): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'Tandroidservice.onBind'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(14): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'Tandroidservice.onCreate'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(15): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'Tandroidservice.onDestroy'
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(16): E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'Tandroidservice.onStart'
```

Comment: CTRL+CLICK TJService, see what methods are marked **virtual**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your only current option is to inherit from a Java class and then use JNI to call into Delphi and do a thread switch to the FMX thread.

My CodeRage 8 session (next week as of time of writing) shows how to do this with an activity. It's much the same process.

That won't help you now, other than to know you can't inherit directly in Delphi from a Java class in Delphi for Android, although in Delphi for iOS you *can* inherit from an Objective-C class.

Comment: good i will watch your session! but will be possible also make a service or application that work in background with this method? i saw a lot of people that ask things like this (broadcast receiver for example for intercept event) on embarcadero forum and other.

Comment: I'll try and rustle up a service or receiver example in a week or two, when I have evenings free again. In short: yes, it should be eminently feasible to do so. It's a bit fiddly, but does work.

Comment: ok thanks! i think with this 2 things we can do about everithing on android for delphi

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe so. To one extent or another. However until the sort out making things easier for these areas outside pure form-based business apps, it is entirely that productive to try and do 'interesting' Android stuff.

Comment: Thanks! A little overdue in arrival, perhaps, but I got here in the end.

Comment: @blong, I am not sure I understand what you mean by saying 'and do a thread switch to the FMX thread'.. Can I inherit from a Java class and override its methods?

Comment: @naXa, not in Delphi, no. Only in Java. Hence why it is complicated. My Android service sample shows what I meant by the bit that confused you. Take a browse through the source at http://blog.blong.com/2013/11/delphi-and-android-services-part-2.html